# How to pass variable to controller without routing?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

```
class HelloController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="hello")
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response($name);
    }
}
```

I would like pass variable $name to indexAction without use routing.

In documentation I found:

```
services:
    # ...

    # explicitly configure the service
    AppBundle\Controller\HelloController:
        public: true
        tags:
            # add multiple tags to control 
            - name: controller.service_arguments
              action: indexAction
              argument: logger
              # pass this specific service id
              id: monolog.logger.doctrine
```

This shows us how to pass another service to the controller, but how to pass a simple variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this inside routing.yml:

```
defaults:
        _controller: AppBundle:Hello:index
        name:        "WhatYouWantToPass"
```